# Why I cant access my new AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, web-hosting, startup, html

I am new to AWS Ec2. I just launch a instance, uploaded a test.php and test.html, both just display a "Hello world" text.

I copied my public DNS: ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute.amazonaws.com

But it always has connection time out.

I managed to connect to the instance, I do a netstat, here is the result:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 XX.XXX.XXX.XX:123           0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               -                   
udp        0      0 XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXX:123     :::*                                    -                   
udp        0      0 ::1:123                     :::*                                    -                   
udp        0      0 :::123                      :::*                                    -                                                 -
```

I cant see the port 80 which is for websvr, so i tried this:

```
ec2-authorize default -p 80
```

BUt it always required me to include the private key and cert, so I include them

```
ec2-authorize default -p 80 -K XXX.pem -C cert-XXX.pem
```

Then, it always said the cert failed to authenticate the SOAP.

Is it something wrong with my cert? (even though I request a new one, it still the same)

Or what should I do to enable to view my webpages (test.php or test.html)?

EDIT:

When I run : sudo tcpdump -pn port 80

Result:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

After open in webpage:

```
09:43:16.353743 IP XXX.XXX.X.XXX.4570 > XX.XXX.XXX.XX.http: Flags [S], seq 1XXXXXXXX6, win 8190, options [mss 1440], length 0
09:43:16.353779 IP XX.XXX.XXX.XX.http > XXX.XXX.X.XXX.4570: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1XXXXXXXX7, win 0, length 0
... etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're connecting to the EC2 instance as ***ec2-user***, as that is the default login for ***Amazon Linux AMI Base 2010.11.1***. But to run the tcpdump command you need to use ***sudo***.

```
sudo tcpdump ...
```

I am not familiar with with the tcpdump command so you will have to sort out the proper syntax on your own.

I may not be familiar with ***tcpdump***, but I am familiar with the ***Amazon Linux AMI Base 2010.11.1***, and based on your question I am wondering if you installed Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc?  These programs are not included by default in Amazon's base AMI.  You can run the following command to see all the packages installed.

```
yum list installed
```

Any programs you need installed that are not listed either need to be installed using ***yum***, or compiled from the source.

```
sudo yum install <program_name_here>
```

For example, to install Apache 2.2 you can run:

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

Here are some good resources:

[HowTo: Get started with Amazon EC2 api tools](http://linuxsysadminblog.com/2009/06/howto-get-started-with-amazon-ec2-api-tools/)

[AWS EC2 Getting Started Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/)

Hope this all helps...

Answer (score 2):

The default is not allowed http connection to the instance:

- open https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/
- NETWORKING & SECURITY->Security Groups
- select default
- add rules to HTTP

Comment: I did. Here is my details for default, Security Group, HTTP:Connection method: HTTP, Protocol: tcp, from port:0, to port:0, source/ip: 0.0.0.0/0. Is my source/ip wrong??

Comment: Ok, then run "tcpdump -pn port 80" and open page. Output copy to question.

Comment: where do I run the command? Terminal after connected to the instances(I use OSX)? It gives me this: -bash: tcpdump: command not found

Comment: What the instances OS?

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI Base 2010.11.1, EBS boot, 64-bit architecture with Amazon EC2 AMI Tools. I guess its Linux

Comment: then use yum to install tcpdump: yum install tcpdump

Comment: When I install, it says: Package 14:tcpdump-4.0.0-3.20090921gitdf3cb4.1.4.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version. Then, I run exactly this command: tcpdump -pn port 80, it says: -bash: tcpdump: command not found. Am I missing something? Sorry, I am new to server stuff :(

Comment: I browse the folder, and I use the commadnd, it gives me this: tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes

Comment: Look like web server not run or iptables REJECT. add "netstat -an | grep \:80" and "iptables -nv -L" outputs.

Comment: While I don't use amazon at all, I do find it weird that your to port is 0 instead of 80.